# Is there any research which compares the bond between biological siblings vs. non-biological siblings or half-siblings?

Tags: physiology, behavior, correlation

A research like: “of 100 families that we studied we found: biological siblings had stronger/weaker bond vs. half-siblings vs non-biological and 40 years later their relationship was found stronger/weaker”

Or kids 40 years after moving out of their parents house children had stronger/weaker bonds with their biological aunt/uncle/grandparent/cousins.

Comment: Hi Honey, Welcome at CogSci. Could you perhaps explain a bit more about what you want to research, and what the (scientific) relevance is of such a research? The more context you provide, the better the answer will be

Comment: @RobinKramer I have a sister, say my mother passed away, and my father marries a women who has 1 daughter. My new step mom also gets pregnant with a new half-sister. My new mother's sister is my new step-aunt. Though I still have my real aunts from my own biological mother, I still have my biological sister just as I have my new step sister & new half-sister. Now let's fast forwards 20 years and Me and all my siblings have grown up and moved out of our parents house.

Comment: Would there be any **extra** bond between me and my biological sister vs me and my step-sister vs. me and my half-sister? Or extra between me and my real aunt vs. my step aunt? Would **blood** ties draw us closer?

Comment: I think others try to express that this is rather a sociology question. Else, I would find this rather an interesting experiment

Comment: @Probably and there's no community for that on stack exchange right?

Comment: @Honey Unfortunately, no, my proposal failed recently. I think this is the closest SE.